# How to plot a 3D surface of a 3D matrix with R

Tags: r, graphics, 3d, geometry-surface

I have 3D matrix of floating point numbers and I would like to produce a smoothed 3D surface of this matrix using R.  Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Now I am using scatterplot3d ... But this function did not produce a smoothed surface

```
x<-read.table("/Users/me/Desktop/data.txt")
scatterplot3d(x$V1, x$V2, x$V3, highlight.3d = TRUE, angle = 30, col.axis = "blue", col.grid = "lightblue", cex.axis = 1.3, cex.lab = 1.1, pch = 20)
```

Comment: Outputting a portion of your data will greatly increase your chances of getting help. You can simply paste the output of `dput(head(x))` into your question above. Thanks

Comment: > dput(head(x))
structure(list(V1 = c(0.01, 0.013971025, 0.019832054, 0.021035526, 
0.023956488, 0.027962379), V2 = c(0.01, 0.011738323, 0.011925891, 
0.011990806, 0.013416452, 0.014304923), V3 = c(8.21e-19, 3.47e-17, 
1.77e-15, 3.64e-15, 1.39e-14, 5.46e-14)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Put the dput dump in the question! The idea here is improved improved questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `mba.surf` from the `MBA` package would be a good choice for the smoothing, and as larrydag above suggests, `persp` would be good to image it. The code below is from the [help page for the mba.surf](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/MBA/html/mba.surf.html) function (swap LIDAR for your 3 column dataframe):

```
data(LIDAR)
mba.int <- mba.surf(LIDAR, 300, 300, extend=TRUE)$xyz.est
# Two ways of imaging....
image(mba.int, xaxs="r", yaxs="r")
persp(mba.int, theta = 135, phi = 30, col = "green3", scale = FALSE,
  ltheta = -120, shade = 0.75, expand = 10, border = NA, box = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to create a 2D matrix (x,y) with the value being the z-axis value you could use the following

```
persp
```

Here is an example from R Graph Gallery. [persp example](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Perspective_plot%3Cbr%3EMaunga_Whau,_One_of_50_Volcanoes_in_the_Auckland_Region_26)

Answer (score 2):

```
require(misc3d)

a <- 2/5

wsqr <-  1 - a^2
w <- sqrt(wsqr)
denom <- function(a,w,u,v) a*((w*cosh(a*u))^2 + (a*sin(w*v))^2)

fx <- function(u,v) -u + (2*wsqr*cosh(a*u)*sinh(a*u)/denom(a,w,u,v))
fy <- function(u,v) 2*w*cosh(a*u)*(-(w*cos(v)*cos(w*v)) - (sin(v)*sin(w*v)))/denom(a,w,u,v)
fz = function(u,v) 2*w*cosh(a*u)*(-(w*sin(v)*cos(w*v)) + (cos(v)*sin(w*v)))/denom(a,w,u,v)


parametric3d(fx = fx, fy = fy, fz = fz, 
             umin = -17, 
             umax = 17, 
             vmin = -77, 
             vmax = 77, 
             n = 100,
             color = c("grey17","grey21","red4","darkred","red4","grey21","grey17"),
             engine = "rgl")
```

[image]